# How to embed llvm into a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c++, llvm, visual-studio-2022

I have my own compiled `LLVM` binaries and I am trying to embed it into my Visual Studio project. [This link](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#embedding-llvm-in-your-project) shows how to do it using `cmake` but im trying to do it using the Visual Studio Solution. How can this be done?

Comment: You probably want to look at Custom Build Steps. This is how you have your project launch external binaries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/understanding-custom-build-steps-and-build-events?view=msvc-170

Comment: why not generate a visual studio project out of the cmake configuration?